# Rails fragment caching with redis not expiring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, redis

I'm using the redis-rails gem for caching on a Rails 5.2 application.

I use fragment caching through the app which successfully caches. Example:

```
<% cache [@site, "header"] do %>
  header goes here
<% end %>
```

The problem is when the object (@site in this case) gets touched and the updated_at timestamp changes, the fragment cache doesn't clear and load in the new content.

Any ideas why?

Comment: what does `ActiveSupport::Cache.expand_cache_key([@site, 'header'])` give you?

Comment: sites/3-20180319043752457651/header

Comment: as you can see, the cache-key has the `updated_at` timestamp in it. so whenever you touch that record, the timestamp will change and thus the cache key. if it does not, something else is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get the cache working as expecting by doing the following:

1. Switched to using Rails 5.2 built in support for the Redis Cache store -  [Rails 5.2: Redis Cache Store](https://www.engineyard.com/blog/rails-5-2-redis-cache-store)
2. Flushed the Redis cache store in rails console using `Redis.current.flushall`

Switching alone didn't fix the problem but flushing the cache did the trick.